# how to Manipulate Handshake message in TLS/SSL in JAVA JSSE?

Tags: sockets, ssl, handshake, jsse

I want to know is if we can handle messages handshake SSL / TLS in Java code, in other words in the query ClientKeyExchange is if we can manipulate or select the key that will be sent to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you install a KeyManager that does what you want in the SSLContext you get the socket from. See the JSSE Reference Guide.